Accessing values in a dictionary with JMESPath in Python when the value is an integer (e.g.: 1)
Using the dictionary:
d = {'1': 'a'}

How can I extract the value a using the JMESPath library in Python?
The following attempts did not work:
import jmespath

value = jmespath.search("1", d) 
# throws jmespath.exceptions.ParseError: invalid token
value = jmespath.search("'1'", d) 
# returns the key '1' instead of the value 'a'


You can directly address an identifier if it is an unquoted-string, so A-Za-z0-9_ and if the string starts with A-Za-z_.

From the grammar rule listed above identifiers can be one or more characters, and must start with A-Za-z_.
An identifier can also be quoted. This is necessary when an identifier has characters not specified in the unquoted-string grammar rule. In this situation, an identifier is specified with a double quote, followed by any number of unescaped-char or escaped-char characters, followed by a double quote.

Source: JMESPath documentation, Identifiers
Since your identifier is 0-9, you have to use double quoted string for this identifier, so "1".
So, your working Python code would be:
import jmespath

d = {'1': 'a'}

value = jmespath.search('"1"', d)

print(value)


Thanks. How would you access a nested 0-9 identifier's value, for instance: d = {b: {'1': 'a'}}?

b can be accessed unquoted, so, b."1"
